# Prove $\log_{a} c + \log_{b} c = \log_{a+b} c$ if and only if $1 + \log_{b} a = \log_{a+b} a$

Tags: logarithms

If a, b and c are positive numbers, than equality $$\log_{a} c + \log_{b} c = \log_{a+b} c$$ is true if and only if $$1 + \log_{b} a = \log_{a+b} a$$
Prove it!

I have looked at the solution but it is not clear for me.

We will prove that if $$\log_{a} c + \log_{b} c = \log_{a+b} c$$
than it is 
$$1 + \log_{b} a = \log_{a+b} a$$

$$\log_{a} c + \log_{b} c = \frac{\log_{a+b} c}{\log_{a+b} a} +\frac{\log_{a+b} c}{\log_{a+b} b} =\log_{a+b} c $$

So this is only thing that is not clear for me how is this equal.
$$\frac{\log_{a+b} c}{\log_{a+b} a} +\frac{\log_{a+b} c}{\log_{a+b} b} =\log_{a+b} c $$

Comment: That looks like the original equation using a change of base formula for logarithms.

Comment: Note that the numerator cancels from both sides, so suffices to show that
$$
\frac{1}{\log_{a+b} a} + \frac{1}{\log_{a+b} b}  = 1
$$
but this seems false. E.g. $a=b=e/2$ you get
$$
1 = \frac{1}{\ln(e/2)} + \frac{1}{\ln(e/2)} = \frac{2}{\ln(e/2)} = \frac{2}{1 - \ln 2}
$$
which is clearly not true since the RHS is approximately $6.5$...

Comment: You are trying to prove that $\log_{a} c + \log_{b} c = \log_{a+b} c$ when you want to prove that if $\log_{a} c + \log_{b} c = \log_{a+b} c$, then $1 + \log_{b} a = \log_{a+b} a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$log_b (a)= \frac{ln (a)}{ln(b)}$$
where 
$ln(a)$ is the natural log of $a$.

Any arbitrary base can be assumed instead of $e$.

So, if

$$log_a (c)+  log_b (c)= log_{a+b} (c)  $$

$$\implies\frac{ln(c)}{ln(a)}+\frac{ln(c)}{ln(b)}=\frac{ln(c)}{ln(a+b)}$$
$$\implies\frac{1}{ln(a)}+\frac{1}{ln(b)}=\frac{1}{ln(a+b)}\ ,\ \  assuming \ \ c\neq1$$
$$\implies1+\frac{ln(a)}{ln(b)}=\frac{ln(a)}{ln(a+b)}$$
$$\implies1+log_b(a)=\frac{ln(a)}{ln(a+b)}$$
$$\implies1+log_b(a)=log_{a+b}(a)$$

The steps are perfectly reversible.

Answer (score 0):

WE have:

$$1+  log_b (a)= log_{a+b} (a)  $$

Let $a=c$ then:

$$ log _a(c)= log _c (c)=1$$

therefore:

$$log _a (c) + log _b (c)= log _{a+b} (c)$$

Comment: Sorry but why is $a=c$

Comment: That is what you can conclude from the given relation. just  substitute c by a and keep a in base on RHS.

Comment: +, You can take any arbitrary value for a including c because there is no limiting condition  such as  $a≠c$ in question.